# C Guessing Game

Tags: c

My program generates numbers that are 999999999999999999999999999999999999. How would i get this program to generate a number from 1 to 100. How would i tell the user how many tries they have left?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int loopcount = 0;

int y = rand()%10;  

int a;

printf("You have 8 chances to guess the right number. Enter your first number.");

while ((loopcount < 9) &&(y>0) &&(y<100))
    {
    printf("enter a number.");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a == y){
        printf(" you have guessed the correct number.");
        loopcount = loopcount + 9;
        break;
        }
    else if (a < y){
        printf("the number is less than");
        loopcount = loopcount + 1;
        continue; 
    }
    else if (a > y){
    printf("the number is greater");
        loopcount = loopcount + 1;
        continue;
    }
    else{
        printf("nothing.");
        break;
    }

}

system("pause");
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "generates numbers that are 999999..."?

Comment: `printf("%d",9-loopcount)` for the 2nd question

Comment: Besides pjs' suggestions, you should note that you're giving the user 9 tries, rather than 8; you're starting at 0 and stopping at 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several suggestions:

1. No need to check that `y > 0` and `y < 100`, that's true by
   construction after applying @MasterOfBinary's fix to do modulo 100 and add 1.
   However, make the modulo 99 if you want a result strictly less than 100.
2. Your response messages are backwards.  If `a < y` their guess is too
   small, not too large.
3. The final `else` clause is useless, make the `else if` above it a
   plain `else`.
4. The `loopcount = loopcount + 9;` statement isn't needed, the
   `break;` immediately after gets you out of the loop.
5. You could replace the other `loopcount` statements with increment
   forms, either `++loopcount;` or `loopcount += 1;`.
6. Your prompt and response strings need newlines (`\n`) at the end.

Comment: when pjs says 'modulo' he means 'remainder after dividing by', which is what the % does

Answer (score 3):

To generate a number from 1 to 100 (inclusive), use the following:

```
int y = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

To tell them how many tries they have left, you need the line

```
printf("Number of tries: %d", 9 - loopcount);
```

at the end of your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't seed the random number generator, `rand` will always produce the same sequence of numbers. To seed it, use the `srand` function. The canonical way to seed it is from the time of day, e.g.:

```
#include <time.h>
...
srand(time(NULL));
```